# How to import modules into a file in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, es6-modules

Currently, I am getting this error when I run my server in docker:

```
import {dataSchema} from "./data-model.js"
>         ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module './data-model.js' does not provide an export named 'dataSchema'
```

Despite having exported it like so:

```
module.exports = {
    dataSchema,
}
```

And importing like so:

```
import {dataSchema} from "./data-model.js"
```

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12
WORKDIR /usr/src/server
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The file that imports the dataSchema is on the same directory level as the file that exports the dataSchema. I can not use the CJS syntax for this.

Currently, I'm trying to console.log() the dataSchema, I'm assuming this isn't working due to problems with my dockerfile. The next thing I suspect, is that I'm supposed to copy the data-model.js file, however I don't see why the COPY . . in my dockerfile wouldn't already do that.

Comment: I highly doubt this code works on Node.js v12. What version are you using locally (outside of Docker)?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev I'm using node 16.17.0, and npm 8.15.0. What makes you doubt this works?

Comment: anyone has a solution for this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well ain't this a blast from the past, almost embaressed by how little I knew just 5 months ago!

I believe the problem was that when you turn a file into a Docker image, it only has access to whatever you designate as the image. So you need to designate a folder, or "level", whatever you want to call them as what you're copying. You can do this by creating a dockerfile on the same level as what you're copying and using the `COPY . .` command to copy over all the files.

For example, you might have a file called `index.js`, where you execute your logic, under a folder called `app` and you might also have another file called `funcs.js` where you're storing your logic and exportng to `index.js`. By creating a docker image out of your folder `app` it will have access to `index.js` and `funcs.js`.

It also helps if you simplify how you organize your working directory.

This is what I ended up using, even now I know it's not the best, but it worked for me:

```
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```